# How can I align headings over stacks of buttons?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the text "Team 1" and "Team 2" above the buttons I have created, so when resizing the page they sit neatly on top of the buttons

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}

button {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn-one {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.btn-two {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  color: red;
}

.first-set {
  display: flex;
}

.second-set {
  display: flex;
}

.third-set {
  display: flex;
}

.teams {
  display: inline;
}

h1 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-scbd">
  <h1 id="scoreboard"> Rugby Scoreboard!
    <h1>
      <h1 class="teams" id="team1"> Team 1 </h1>
      <h1 class="teams" id="team2"> Team 2 </h1>
      <div class="first-set">
        <button class="btn-one" onclick="try()"> TRY! </button>
        <button class="btn-two" onclick="try()"> TRY! </button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-set">
        <button class="btn-one" onclick="converted"> Converted! </button>
        <button class="btn-two" onclick="converted"> Converted! </button>
      </div>
      <div class="third-set">
        <button class="btn-one" onclick="penalty"> Penalty/Drop Goal </button>
        <button class="btn-two" onclick="penalty"> Penalty/Drop Goal </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have changed the extra headings and probably because I am only just starting out, this is only day 6 of learning

Comment: It s perfect for 6 days of learning only!

Answer (score 1):

- Use a two-column layout to keep related items in a stack.
- Use the `space-evenly`, `space-around`, or `space-between` `justify-content` property value to position the columns.
- Don't use more than one level 1 heading. Use [good document structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes).
- Fix the faulty closing h1 tag on your first heading.
- Don't put text alignment on the entire body. Use it sparingly and locally.
- Use semantic class names so you aren't repeating yourself. They should be reusable.
- Use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) instead of inline JavaScript. Use an embedded script tag or an external script file.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.try-btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const team = btn.closest('[data-team]').getAttribute('data-team');
    console.log('Try button clicked for team ' + team + '.');
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.converted-btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const team = btn.closest('[data-team]').getAttribute('data-team');
    console.log('Converted button clicked for team ' + team + '.');
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.penalty-btn').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const team = btn.closest('[data-team]').getAttribute('data-team');
    console.log('Penalty button clicked for team ' + team + '.');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  margin           : 10px auto;
  width            : 100px;
  border-radius    : 50%;
  padding          : 10px;
  text-shadow      : 0px 0px 1px black;
  border           : 1px solid black;
  }
.text-center {
  text-align       : center;
  }
.btn-one {
  background-color : red;
  color            : white;
  }
.btn-two {
  background-color : lightyellow;
  color            : red;
  }
.flex-row,
.flex-col {
  display          : flex;
  }
.flex-col {
  flex-direction   : column;
  }
.space-around {
  justify-content  : space-evenly;
  }
```

```html
<div class="full-scbd">
  <h1 id="scoreboard" class="text-center">Rugby Scoreboard!</h1>

  <div class="flex-row space-around">
    <div class="flex-col text-center" data-team="1">
      <h2 class="teams" id="team1"> Team 1 </h2>
      <button class="btn-one try-btn"> TRY! </button>
      <button class="btn-one converted-btn"> Converted! </button>
      <button class="btn-one penalty-btn"> Penalty/Drop Goal </button>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-col text-center" data-team="2">
      <h2 class="teams" id="team2"> Team 2 </h2>
      <button class="btn-two try-btn"> TRY! </button>
      <button class="btn-two converted-btn"> Converted! </button>
      <button class="btn-two penalty-btn"> Penalty/Drop Goal </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, but please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged. Keep up the good work.